# How limit number of result in ng2-autocomplete in angular2

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I am new in **angular2**. I created a dropdown using **ng2-autocomplete** & its work fine.
But how could I limit the search result(s) or how could I place scroll bar on it ?

Here my code:

```
<input ng2-auto-complete [(ngModel)]="contact.pCity"
  [source]="citySuggestions.bind(this)"
  list-formatter="pCity"
  display-property-name="pCity"
  placeholder="Search by City"
  class="form-control1"
  style="border-radius:0px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use this https://github.com/ng2-ui/auto-complete ?

You need `max-num-list` attribute. Here is list of all attributes: https://github.com/ng2-ui/auto-complete#attributes

Comment: any exceptions? I am not sure search is not happening because of extra attr.

Comment: is it possible to set scroll bar on result data